# powebi: Get the number of values associated to each value in other column

Tags: powerbi

Hello i am using power bi,
In the table shown below i am trying to calculate the number of "Occupation_id' that are associated to each " Skill_id" , i tried the formula as it is shown in "column" but it gives me all the values as 1,
Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

The formula i used : `Column = CALCULATE(COUNT(occupations_skills[occupation_id]), ALLEXCEPT(occupations_skills,occupations_skills[id]))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/417uh.png)

Answer (score 0):

ok i knew the answer i did a mistake in the code: `Column = CALCULATE(COUNT(occupations_skills[occupation_id]), ALLEXCEPT(occupations_skills,occupations_skills[skill_id]))`